# Powershell, pipe list of arguments to a command

Tags: powershell

I am working on a powershell v3 script to create users in Active Directory.

I'm using the new-ADUser comlet for that. I want to execute one command to create the user and set all the options in one set, but given that I have so many settings to set, I would end up with a really long command that is hard to read. Instaed I prefer to create something, pipe that to new-aduser and achieve the same.

I tried the following:

```
$param = @()
$param.Name = "Test Name"
$param.GivenName = "Test"
$param.Surname = "Test"
$param.Enabled = 1

$param | new-aduser
```

However, if I do the following it works:

```
new-aduser -name "Test Name" -GivenName "Test" -Surname "Test" -Enabled 1
```

If I execute this, it says I can only do this if the naming is correct. It is... So what am I doing wrong, or is there another way on how I can have the parameters listed below eachother and send that to new-aduser? Can I convert the array to an object somehow and make it work, and if so, how?

If I can somehow just use only new-aduser and list them below eachother, that would work too, but I don't think Powershell is as loose with enters as php is.

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: How about splatting?

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT thanks, but indeed that's not what I'm after. I already have something like that, but the few params I listed was an example. My actual list of params is over 20 params long, that is really hard to track because the row is very long and unreadable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the
[Hey, Scripting Guy! Blog](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2012/09/03/use-powershell-to-create-a-user-in-active-directory/)
comes this example:

```
Import-Module activedirectory

$users = @{
 "name" = "fred"
 "givenName" = "manfred"
 "l" = "lexington"
}

New-ADUser @users
```

A [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44270448/165358)
also explains how to use the `OtherAttributes` parameter, if you need to:

```
$users = @{ 
    "name" = “fred 
    "givenName" = “Manfred" 
    "l" = "lexington"
    "OtherAttributes" = @{ 
        'extensionAttrbute1' = "Test"
     }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, this works. :) So instead of doing $array | new-aduser, its new-aduser @array. cool. :)